# Image File Not Viewable After Editing

Tags: joomla-3.4

I'm trying to resize a .png image called bottom-fade.png. Without modification the image looks like the following in joomla
[image: unmodified]

But when I try to modify the file by resizing it goes blank as shown below

[image: modified]

Can someone let me know why resizing (or modifying the image) results in losing the colours?

carlton

Comment: May be an idea to post this one on the Joomla Github Issue Tracker

Comment: seems like a bug in template image editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you resizing it? Some tools are not very good with resizing png images because of transparency. If you don't have Photoshop and you want to resize a png image then try pixlr (their online desktop), it works very well.

If you're trying to resize the png image using PHP, then can you post your code? The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257405/why-is-resized-png-image-so-much-bigger-than-original-image) should work.

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm trying to resize it.. here is the code  #bottom_fade {
 width: 6000px;
 height: 200px;
 z-index: 99;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: url('../images/style1/bottom-fade4.png') bottom center no-repeat;

Comment: And yes, its transparent image.

Comment: Pixlr worked. Thank youi